# How can I simplify this process of splitting/counting numpy subarrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean, cluster-analysis

I have a large dataset for which I would like to implement an efficient numpy solution. As a simpler example, consider a small array of numbers.

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
```

The code further below is very close to being my ideal solution, but I have hit a roadblock. First, I create a boolean mask to indicate the indices of the array at which array values are greater than a pre-defined lower bound and lesser than a pre-defined upper bound. I then split the boolean mask into subarrays, each of which consist of identical values by consecutive index. As an example, `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` splits into `[0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1, 1]`. Lastly, I would like to take all subarrays consisting of only `1`s and split them into individual subarrays. As an example, `[1, 1, 1]` should split into `[1], [1], [1]`.

**The code below does most of what I'd like, but in an inconvenient fashion. I would like all subarrays to be stored in a single array, from which I can count the number of subarrays and the number of elements in each subarray.** Unfortunately, this is tricky for me as the function outputs are numpy arrays that are `array(...)` instead of just `(...)`. I'm thinking there's a way to do this using `np.ndarray.T` that I get `True`/`False` values from and apply the `axis` [kwarg](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to, though I have not had any success implementing this approach so far. How can I simplify this process?

```
def get_groups_by_difference(array, difference):
    """ This function splits arrays into subarrays in which every element is identical. """
    return np.split(array[:], np.where(abs(np.diff(array)) != difference)[0] + 1)

def check_consecutive_nested_arrays(array, repeated_value):
    """ This function returns a boolean array mask - True if all elements of a subarray contain the repeated value; False otherwise. """
    return np.array([np.all(subarray == repeated_value) for subarray in array])

def get_solution(array, lbound, ubound):
    # get boolean mask for array values within bounds
    bool_cnd = np.logical_and(array>lbound, array<ubound)
    # convert True/False into 1/0
    bool_cnd = bool_cnd * 1
    # split array into subarrays of identical values by consecutive index
    stay_idx = np.array(get_groups_by_difference(bool_cnd, 0))
    # find indices of subarrays of ones
    bool_chk = check_consecutive_nested_arrays(stay_idx, 1)
    # get full subarrays of ones 
    ones_sub = stay_idx[bool_chk]
    return bool_cnd, stay_idx, bool_chk, ones_sub

bool_cnd, stay_idx, bool_chk, ones_sub = get_solution(arr, 3, 7)
print(bool_cnd)
>> [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
print(stay_idx)
>> [array([0, 0, 0]) array([1, 1, 1]) array([0, 0, 0, 0])]
print(bool_chk)
>> [False  True False]
print(ones_sub)
>> [array([1, 1, 1])]
```

My goal is to obtain an array result like the following:

```
[[0 0 0]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[0 0 0 0]]
```

This way, I can find the number of elements per subarray and the number of subarrays (ie, `5` subarrays with lengths of `[3, 1, 1, 1, 4]`.

Comment: Try and be more explicit about what you expect the end result to be like.

Comment: I just updated the post at the very bottom. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

```
np.split(a, 1 + np.where(a[1:]|a[:-1])[0])
```

should do what you want. Here `a` is the vector of ones and zeros.

This uses the fact that your final result can be obtained by splitting left and right of *every* 1.

Comment: I am familiar with numpy where and I’ve checked that your algorithm works. But, I do not understand how/why the indexing of a in the numpy where clause works. Could you please explain how/why your way of indexing the array like that works?

Comment: @mikey `a[1:]` is `a` with the 1st element left out, `a[:-1]` is `a` with the last element left out. In between you have `|` which is the 'or' operator so the result willl be one shorter than `a` and have one where `a` has one and one left of every one in `a`. You can check that if you align this with the "gaps" of `a` it will have ones everywhere where there should be cut. Because `split` starts counting left of the zeroth element we need to add `1`. The `[0]` in the end is because `where` returns a list of arrays (one for each dim).

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you then process your results like so:

```
ret = []
for idx, check in zip(stay_idx, bool_chk):
    if check:
        ret += idx.tolist()
    else:
        ret.append(idx)
ret = np.array(ret)
```

Not particularly beautiful, but maybe good enough for your specific needs.